# Better way to reorder list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

So I have a small data like this:

```
data = [
    {"Name":"Arab","Code":"Zl"},
    {"Name":"Korea","Code":"Bl"},
    {"Name":"China","Code":"Bz"}
]
```

I want to find a graph so that the x-axis is: "Bl", "Bz", "Zl" (alphabetic order) 
and the y-axis is: "Korea", "China", "Arab" (corresponding to the codenames).

I thought of:

```
new_data = {}
for dic in data:
    country_data = dic["Name"]
    code_data = dic["Code"]
    new_data[code_data] = country_data

code_data = []
for codes in new_data.keys():
    code_data.append(codes)
code_data.sort()

name_data = []
for code in code_data:
    name_data.append(new_data[code])
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Perhaps by not creating a new dictionary?

Comment: `pairs = sorted((d['Code'], d['Name']) for d in data)`

Answer (score 1):

So here's the data:

```
data = [
    {"Name":"Arab","Code":"Zl"},
    {"Name":"Korea","Code":"Bl"},
    {"Name":"China","Code":"Bz"}
]
```

To create a new sorted list:

```
new_list = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['Code'])
```

If you don't want to get a new list:

```
data[:] = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['Code'])
```

The result is:

```
[{'Code': 'Bl', 'Name': 'Korea'}, {'Code': 'Bz', 'Name': 'China'}, {'Code': 'Zl', 'Name': 'Arab'}]
```

I hope I could help you!

Comment: The second version also creates a new list object. It just binds this new list to the old variable. If you *really* want to mutate the old list object, use slice assignment `data[:] = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['Code'])`.

Comment: Yes but it's the same effect

Comment: Imagine that code in a function with data being passed as an argument. The effect visible to the caller will be vastly different. Also, the "not a new list" statement in itself is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to produce same results:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [
    {"Name": "Arab",  "Code": "Zl"},
    {"Name": "Korea", "Code": "Bl"},
    {"Name": "China", "Code": "Bz"}
]

sorted_data = ((d["Code"], d["Name"]) for d in sorted(data, key=itemgetter("Code")))
code_data, name_data = (list(item) for item in zip(*sorted_data))

print(code_data)  # -> ['Bl', 'Bz', 'Zl']
print(name_data)  # -> ['Korea', 'China', 'Arab']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `operator.itemgetter` and unpacking via `zip`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

_, data_sorted = zip(*sorted(enumerate(data), key=lambda x: x[1]['Code']))

codes, names = zip(*map(itemgetter('Code', 'Name'), data_sorted))

print(codes)
# ('Bl', 'Bz', 'Zl')

print(names)
# ('Korea', 'China', 'Arab')
```